# file io working in netbeans but not eclipse

Tags: eclipse, netbeans

I have the exact same code snippet below running in netbeans and eclipse. It works in netbeans but not eclipse. The code is:

```
public void readDocument() {
   String filename ="hsk1";
   String baseDirectory = "c:\\er\\development\\first\\"; // This is the Eclipse directory
   String documentDirectory = baseDirectory +filename+".txt";                   
   File f = new File(documentDirectory);                  
   String absolutePath = f.getAbsolutePath();
   Boolean fileExists = f.exists();
```

in netbeans absolutePath is: c:\er\development\first\hsk1.txt and fileExists is true. (and goes on to read the file just fine)

in eclipse absolutePath is: /c:\er\development\first\hsk1.txt and fileExists is false.

Don't know where the forward slash is coming from or what I should do. Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Chris

Comment: What platform (Windows, Mac, Linux, Unix) is Eclipse running on?

Comment: Try to debug the code and check the value of **documentDirectory** variable

Comment: Thanks greg and Ahandrayya - I'm using Windows. when I use the following File s0 = getFileStreamPath("flash.txt");
            String s1 = s0.getPath(); I get a path that starts with a none windows /data/data - I can't figure out how to tell it to go to C:/er/development/flash.txt. I've put the file in assests I've tried full references such as "C:\\er\\development\\flash.txt" but to no avail. I'm going nuts.